# Como ignorar um "Duplicate entry error" no MYSQL e inserir o restante não duplicado

Tags: c#, mysql

Como ignorar uma `exception` e inserir o restante dos campos quando eu recebo esse erro no MYSQL utilizando mysql .NET connector? O meu `try catch` é o seguinte:

```
try
    {
        conexao.Open();
        MySqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        return reader.GetString("ID");

    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        if (e.Number == 1062) //Duplicate entry
        {
            MySqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            return reader.GetString("ID");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(Query);
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
            return "Error";
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(Query);
        Debug.WriteLine(e);
        return "Error";
    }
finally
{

        conexao.Close(); //Fechando a conexão
}
```

Naturalmente quando tem email duplicado dentro dos `values` da minha query eu caio no primeiro `catch (MySqlException e)` dentro dele eu comecei a filtar o erro pelo `if (e.Number == 1062` ele verifica e cai certinho dentro desse `if`, porém quando eu vou executar o comando `MySqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();` o MYSQL adverte novamente do erro e código vai para o `finally` e digamos se eu tenho 1 email duplicado dentre 100 emails, eu gostaria de inserir 99 e ignorar o email que já existe na tabela.

Comment: Pensou em fazer um select verificando se o e-mail já existe?

Comment: São muitos emails, é um INSERT com tipo N números de emails

Comment: calmai, você esta utilizando 1 insert para adicionar vários e-mails? O seu banco esta normalizado?

Comment: @GabrielColetta sim, o que acontece é eu analiso uma pasta de um email(no caso o email da empresa) e procuro por emails enviados com erro para limpar a minha outra base de emails, para não ficar requisitando o banco toda hora eu dou um `INSERT` na tabela `EMAILS_ERROS` com varios emails juntos(`INSERT INTO table VALUES(),(),()`

Comment: E está muito bem normalizado.

Comment: nunca usei o INSERT assim e nem sabia que tinha como.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html da uma olhada